# Sparse Approximation in the Mahalanobis Distance

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, optimization, sparsity, mahalanobis-distance

Given a vector $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $k < n$, finding the best $k$-sparse approximation to $z$ in terms of the Euclidean distance means solving
$$\min_{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x||_0 \le k\}} ||z - x||_2$$ This can easily be done by choosing $x$ such that it consists of the $k$ largest components of $z$ in terms of $| \cdot |$ and zero in every other component.

I was now thinking about what happens if we slightly modify the question to allow for other metrics on $\mathbb{R}^n$. For example, what would happen if we instead try to solve
$$\min_{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x||_0 \le k\}} (x-z)^TA(x-z)$$
for a symmetric positive definite matrix $A$? I guess this is much harder, but are there good algorithms that do this?

Comment: Could you please state the definition of $\|x\|_0$?

Comment: $\|x\|_0$ is the number of nonzero elements in a vector $x$. It is not a norm, but can be shown to be the limit of $\|x\|_p$ as $p \rightarrow 0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $A$ is symmetric definite positive, we can write $A = S^2$ where $S$ is a square-root matrix of $A$. Introducing $y:= Sz$, your problem can now be rewritten as
$$\min_{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x||_0 \le k\}} \Vert Sx - y\Vert^2.$$

This is a quite well-known problem, which I think is known as [sparse regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_approximation), related to the [compressed sensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_sensing) problem, a research area which was popular around the 2000's. There is a **huge** litterature on this. I will give a couple of pointers to your question about how to solve it:

- One approach is to try to solve directly this nonconvex problem. You can try for instance a projected-gradient method :
  $$x^{k+1} = P_k(x^k - \lambda S^\top(S x^k - y))$$
  where $\lambda < 2 / \Vert A \Vert$, and $P_k$ is the projection onto $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x||_0 \le k\}$ which is quite easy to compute (as you wrote yourself, it sets to zero the $n-k$ smallest coefficients). This sequence $(x^k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is guaranteed to converge (because the problem is semi-algebraic, see the arguments in Example 5.4 of [Convergence of descent methods for semi-algebraic and tame problems](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-011-0484-9)). But the limit is not guranteed to be a solution of the problem, because the problem is nonconvex.
- An other approach, widely used in statistics and signal processing is to consider a convex approximation of the problem, known as the [LASSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)) :
  $$\min_{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x||_1 \le k\}} \Vert Sx - y\Vert^2.$$
  Replacing $\Vert \cdot \Vert_0$ with $\Vert \cdot \Vert_1$ makes now the problem convex.

  - Solutions of the LASSO can be efficiently approximated by sequences generated by a projection-gradient algorithm (same as above, but we project now onto a L1-ball, which is quite the same as projecting onto the simplex) ; but there are plenty of other algorithms at hand to do this as well.
  - Of course the LASSO is not exactly our original problem, so what are we losing here? The fact is that there are guarantees which ensure that *both problems have the same solution*. For instance, if $S$ is injective, which is our case here since you assume $A$ to be definite positive (see Proposition 2.1 in [*The Convex Geometry of Linear Inverse Problems*](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10208-012-9135-7)).
- A last note, in case you start to investigate more on the topic with those keywords. The problem you consider is equivalent to
  $$\min_{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : \Vert Sx - y\Vert^2 \le \varepsilon\}} \Vert x \Vert_0$$
  and
  $$\min_{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n\}} \lambda \Vert x \Vert_0 + \Vert Sx - y\Vert^2$$
  with a suitable choice of $\lambda,\varepsilon$ depending on $k$.
  Depending on what you'll read, one form or the other will be discussed.